# Dúvida com relacionamento de tabelas MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Boa tarde pessoal, minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Atualmente possuo 3 tabelas no banco de dados.

As tabelas:

- investors_positivador (cod_cliente, net_cliente, cod_assessor)
- investors_saldo_clientes (cod_cliente, nome_cliente)
- investors_base_assessores (cod_assessor, nome_assessor)

Gostaria de obter as seguintes colunas como resultado da consulta sql:

- cod_cliente
- nome_cliente
- net_cliente
- nome_assessor

O resultado do select precisa conter todos os códigos dos clientes da coluna (cod_cliente) da tabela (investors_positivador).

O que acontece é que eu consigo chegar a obter as informações (cod_cliente, nome_cliente, net_cliente), porém o nome_assessor não consigo, pois teria que referenciar a coluna cod_assessor (investors_positivador) à coluna nome_assessor (investors_base_assessores)

Abaixo está o comando que cheguei e consegui obter todos os dados (com excessão do nome_assessor):

```
SELECT investors_positivador.cod_cliente, investors_positivador.net_em_m, investors_saldo_financeiro.nome_cliente
FROM     investors_positivador INNER JOIN
                  investors_saldo_financeiro ON investors_positivador.cod_cliente = investors_saldo_financeiro.cod_cliente
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa adicionar a sua consulta a tabela `investors_base_assessores`; com isso, poderá trazer no *select* o `nome_assessor`

```
SELECT ip.cod_cliente, ip.net_em_m, isf.nome_cliente, iba.nome_assessor
FROM investors_positivador ip
INNER JOIN investors_saldo_financeiro isf ON ip.cod_cliente = isf.cod_cliente
INNER JOIN investors_base_assessores iba ON iba.cod_assessor = ip.cod_assessor
```

obs: adicionai *alias* às tabelas pra ficar mais fácil de entender a consulta.